# Set cookies in node.js in different domains

Tags: php, node.js, cookies, express

I'm developing a real time chat component for existing system written by PHP which is running on LAMP stack. I used **node.js**, **Express.js** and **Socket.io** for the implementation. Lets say the system is running on a vhost, http://product.loc. I am running the node server in 127.0.0.1:3000.

My chat component which is written in side the system initiates a socket with node server. It works fine. But, i wrote a simple cookie authentication logic in node server, it does not work. cookies are not parsing the node server. i know this is a cross domain issue. But no idea how to resolve this as i am a newbie to Node stuff. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Use access keys instead, pass it with your url parameters like `?key=3sdf3s3r3f23sf3asdl`

Comment: Thanks dude. i'd try with that.